# python regular expression to extract date

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to extract a date from a text.Text must contain 'Expiration Date:'
some where in line. i have written this python script

```
date = re.findall('Expiration Date:*(.+)', w.text)
```

but this is not working in some case. Like in case of 'Registrar Registration Expiration Date:'.
Also, how can check for multiple types of match like if the text has 'Expiry date' in place of 'Expiration date'

Comment: Providing full expected input/output (e.g. input looks like: Registrar Registration Expiration Date: 9/10/86, Expiry date: 02-02-2002, etc, output looks like: 9/10/86) and listing as many expected edge cases as possible would be helpful (e.g. case insensitivity, extra characters/spaces, etc).

Comment: Change your pattern to only look for the word date?  You should use an online regex tester (one that uses Python flavored regex) to fine tune your pattern.

Comment: @ggorlen if Input is 'Registrar Registration Expiration Date: 2020-09-28T12:35:25Z' output should be '2020-09-28T12:35:25Z'

Comment: It is working fine when line contain only 'Expiration Date: 2020-09-28T12:35:25Z'.i.e if starting with 'Expiration Date:' .

Answer (score 3):

You can use this regex:

```
exp_date = re.findall(r'exp\w+ date[ :]*\d+[ -/]\d+[ -/]\d+',w.text,re.IGNORECASE)
```

this will match both expiry and expiration with both upper and lower case and will also match dates with different formats like:

- 2010/01/01
- 2010-01-01
- 2010 01 01

**Demo**

```
string = "lorem ipusm expiry date : 2010-2-1 dolor sit expiration date : 2010/2/1 amet"
match = re.findall(r'exp\w+ date[ :]*\d+[ -/]\d+[ -/]\d+',string,re.IGNORECASE)
print(match)
# output: ['expiry date : 2010-2-1', 'expiration date : 2010/2/1']
```

Comment: what if I want only date part, not 'expiry date'?

Comment: split each item on spaces and get the last item. I have used this list comprehension to get the list of dates.

`[item.split(" ")[-1] for item in match]`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `|` to club multiple regex condition and also use `re.IGNORECASE` to ignore case

**Demo:**

```
import re
s = """Registrar Registration Expiration Date: 10/4/2018
Expiry date: 10/4/2018 """

print(re.findall('Expiration Date:*(.+)|Expiry Date:*(.+)', s, re.IGNORECASE))    #or re.I
```

Answer (score 0):

You can as well do it with one expression without using or

```
import re
s = """Registrar Registration Expiration Date: 10/4/2018
Expiry date: 10/4/2018 """

print(re.findall('Exp\w+ Date:*(.+)', s, re.IGNORECASE))
```

it matches any statement that contains Exp and any word character followed by Date. so it can either be Expiry or Expiration